# One of the categories show incorrectly unanswered questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, unanswered-questions

I think one of the categories (tags) has a bug?

If you go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-grid2?sort=unanswered you should see posts that are unanswered, however several of the posts already have answers. A (very) similar category https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-grid?sort=unanswered behaves correctly. The only difference between the two, that I can see, is that [selenium-grid2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-grid2) does not have a wiki summary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think anything is broken here. The definition of "unanswered" used by the tabs is "no **upvoted** answers" (not "no answers posted at all").

Comment: The second question on the first link has 2 votes.

Comment: The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21389080/selenium-grid-configuration-of-timeouts) has upvotes, but the [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21443561/19405) is at 0.